# How can I compare rows of two similar tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

These TSQL tables are exact but I can't guarantee that.  I cannot guarantee which rows will be non-existent in either table.

[image: Image of both tables]

What I want to be able to do is to subtract one from the other into a new table. For instance, "Agg Asslt" should have a column value for "OffenseCount" of 6.  However, "Theft Veh" should be -25.  If a row does not exist in one or the other table, I will be either subtracting 0 or subtracting from 0.  These are always integers. I hope this makes sense.  If the row does not exist in either table, the point is moot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can multiple rows for a given value of AbreviatedOfffense exist in the same table? If so, what do you expect in your output? Don't guess - go look. If you want to assume that it is unique, then think about enforcing that assumption with a constraint. Why? Because duplicates are just a fact of life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.offense, t2.offense),
       coalesce(t1.count, 0) - coalesce(t2.count, 0)
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.offense = t2.offense
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  Perfect.